# How to create set of image files in folder using python and PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am resizing a set of images and storing resized image to new folder.my sample code is

```
import cv2
import PIL
import Image
import os

def resize_all(path1,path2):
 resolution = (200,200)
 scaler = Image.ANTIALIAS
 if not os.path.exists(path2):
    os.makedirs(path2)
 listing=os.listdir(path1)
 for file in listing:
    img=Image.open(path1 + file)
    res=img.resize(resolution , Image.ANTIALIAS)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2, res),'image')

def main():
 resize_all('d:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\birds\\','d:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\new\\')

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

But when i execute i am getting error as
Full Traceback added **EDIT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Emmanu/ImageClassification/preprocessing.py", line 20, in <module>
if __name__ == '__main__':main()
File "D:/Emmanu/ImageClassification/preprocessing.py", line 18, in main
resize_all('d:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\birds\\','d:\\Emmanu\\project-data\\new\\')
File "D:/Emmanu/ImageClassification/preprocessing.py", line 15, in resize_all
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2, res),'image')
File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 67, in join
p_drive, p_path = splitdrive(p)
File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
if len(p) > 1:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 512, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __len__
```

Comment: Give us the full stack trace please

Comment: @Natecat I have added full code.Full stack trace is full code isn't it

Comment: `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2, res),'image')` -> `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path2, file),res)`

Comment: No, stack trace is full traceback of exception that Python prints when your code crashes. It even says something like "stack trace" at the top.

Comment: Are you using the old PIL or [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.x/)? Try this import in place of `import PIL` and `import Image`: `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: @PM2Ring PIL version 1.1.7 latest version.Tried replacement but still Error

Comment: Ok. But it's weird that `import Image` doesn't give you `ImportError: No module named Image`. That's what I get on Python 2.6.6, with PIL.VERSION=='1.1.7' and PIL.PILLOW_VERSION=='2.9.0'

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Finally got answer, Modified the for loop

```
for i,file in enumerate(listing):
    img=Image.open(path1 + file)
    res=img.resize(resolution , Image.ANTIALIAS)
    res.save(path2+'h{}.jpg'.format(i))
```

Now all my images are resized and saved to a new folder